# Настройка окружения файл composer.json

Tags: composer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть в CMS два окружения admin (темплейты) и cms (движок). Каждое окружение имеет свои контролеры и роуты (под одинаковыми именами). Каждое окружение должно работать отдельно, для того оно и отделяется от другого. Но только происходит выход по URL пути .../admin/login, где должен подтягиваться контролер из окружения admin, а цепляет контролера из cms окружения.
Подозрение на composer настройки или Nginx, есть специалисты?

```
{
"name": "alex/alex",
 "require": {},

"autoload": {

"psr-4": {
    "Engine\\": "engine",
    "Cms\\": "cms",
    "Admin\\": "admin",
    "Engine\\DI\\": "engine/DI"

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была не в composer, а в конфигурации nginx...
Проблема решилась добавлением дополнительного location /admin/login в конфиг nginx и добавления роута в контролер на этот location /admin/login